# Elasticsearch fails sorting because of empty string

Tags: elasticsearch

Basically, the json structure for the field looks like this:

```
"myflag": {
        "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "case_insensitive"
            }
          }
      }
```

If I have these 5 entries:

```
A
a
B

C
```

they will be sorted correctly which means:

```
A
a
B
C
```

And 1 row with an empty value.

However, it looks like the empty row (quite sure of that) is not set. It is null or undefined.
In this case the sorting works well.

But as soon as I change the empty row with a value and THEN clear it, the sorting will then be incorrect.

So for example, in the example above, I set the value for the empty value, so at the end in db I have this:

```
A
a
B
Z
C
```

The sorting will still be correct, showing:

```
A
a
B
C
Z
```

But as soon as I clear the value in an entry, that entry will be first in the list. So if I clear the value of the former Z, the sort will give me:

```
(EMPTY)
A
a
B
C
```

EMPTY row became first.
Is there another parameter that need to be added to the schema?

Running

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/tambur/_settings
```

gives this:

```
analysis: {
normalizer: {
case_insensitive: {
filter: "lowercase"
}
}
```

}

Comment: Strange. Which version of Elasticsearch are you using? The above mappings shows you've used a custom `normalizer`. Could you add the details of this `case_insensitive` normalizer too?

Comment: Does **EMPTY** mean an empty string or a **null** value ? I believe that an empty string will always appear first.

Comment: @Kamal I dont understand the question. Can you please explain?

Comment: However, this is the elastic version Im using: number: "5.2.2",
build_hash: "f9d9b74",
build_date: "2017-02-24T17:26:45.835Z",
build_snapshot: false,
lucene_version: "6.4.1"

Comment: Sure. Just execute this `GET <your_index_name>/_settings` and update the question. That would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexical order used by elasticsearch sorts empty string as first. To change the order for an empty string you will have to use a custom sort function :

```
{
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['myflag.raw'].value == '' ? 'zzzzzzzz' : doc['myflag.raw'].value"
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Here `'zzzzzzzz'` corresponds to the last expected word using alphabetical order. I could not find another way to state explicitly **last position**

Comment: The query is now like this: queryBody.sort: [ { 'myflag.raw': { missing: '_last', order: 'asc' } } ] .      But Im still getting the same sorting with empty string first.

Comment: Sorry I previously did not understand your question. I have updated the answer for **empty** string instead of a **null** field.